# tell application - string vs. string?

Tags: applescript, tell

If I run:

```
tell application "Maps"
    set miniaturized of windows to false
end tell
```

...this works fine

Yet, when I run:

```
set applicationName to "Maps"
tell application applicationName
    set miniaturized of windows to false
end tell
```

...I get:

Maps got an error: Can’t make |miniaturized| of every window into type reference.

I also tried:

```
tell application (applicationName as string)
    ...
end tell
```

...but I get the same error.

I'm new to Apple Script and not quite understanding the nuances between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of `tell application` is required be a literal string (a constant) because the terminology is evaluated at compile time.

The alternative is an `using terms from application` block but the argument requires a literal string, too

```
using terms from application "Maps"

end using terms from
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me using the latest version of Sierra

```
set applicationName to "Maps"
tell application applicationName
    tell its windows
        set miniaturized to false
    end tell
end tell
```

[image]

This also works for me

```
set applicationName to "Maps"
tell application applicationName's windows to set miniaturized to false
```

[image]

Comment: I'm running Sierra as well (10.12.6), but neither of these work on my machine.  They don't produce any errors, but they don't restore the windows either.