# passing a variable to a handler(function) in applescript

Tags: applescript

`test_two()` and `test_three work()`, but `test_one()` does not.  Why is that?  How do I pass the argument into the handler and use it as a local variable?

```
set the_application to "Safari"
test_one(the_application)
on test_one(the_application)
    tell application the_application
        make new document with properties {URL:"http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
    end tell
end test_one
# ----

test_two()
on test_two()
    tell application "Safari"
        make new document with properties {URL:"http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
    end tell
end test_two
# ----

set the_application to "Safari"
test_three(the_application)
on test_three(the_application)
    tell application the_application
        activate
    end tell
end test_three
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [tell application - string vs. string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46854193/tell-application-string-vs-string)

Comment: I don't think so.  In test_three I don't use a string literal for the argument in the 'tell application' statement, and it works fine.

Comment: Because `activate` is a global command which every application responds to, even if it lacks an AppleScript dictionary.

Comment: Hmm.  So, I can sometimes use a variable in the 'tell application' statement, and sometimes not, depending on what actions I use inside the tell block?  So `activate` is a global command, but `make` is a ...local command?  Is there a list of these somewhere?  I have not been able to find very good documentation on applescript.

Comment: And, is it only the `tell application` that has this problem?

Comment: The global commands are `launch`, `activate`, `reopen`, `quit`, `version`, `is running` and `frontmost`. And yes, the reason is described in the linked answer.

Comment: Ok, thanks a lot.  That gives me something to go off of.  In the other answer, you mention that the `tell` statement is evaluated at compile time.  Are there other statements for which this is true?

Comment: Actually the entire code is going to be compiled. But the `tell application` statement is a special case because it evaluates the particular terminology of the target application therefore it cannot be a variable. And like in the other compiled languages for example you cannot create compound variable names.

Comment: I appreciate the help.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my other working solution, maybe, better than my first one:

```
set the_application to "Safari"
test_one(the_application)

on test_one(the_application)
    set theScript to "tell application \"" & the_application & "\"
make new document with properties {URL:\"http://www.stackoverflow.com\"}
    end tell"
    run script theScript
end test_one
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want use some **terms common to multiple applications**, you can do it **using terms from one of them**. This terms will work for other applications as well. You can indicate in the code's first line the **name of any application**, which has command **make new document with properties** and property **URL**,

```
set the_application to "some Safari like application"
test_one(the_application)

on test_one(the_application)
    using terms from application "Safari"
        tell application the_application
            make new document with properties {URL:"http://www.stackoverflow.com"}
        end tell
    end using terms from
end test_one
```

Other example (creates new folder on the desktop):

```
set the_application to "Finder"
test_one(the_application)

on test_one(the_application)
    using terms from application "System Events"
        tell application the_application
            make new folder with properties {name:"TestFolder"}
        end tell
    end using terms from
end test_one
```

Comment: Note that other than a few basic terms from the Standard Suite, successful usage of terms and event codes between different applications would be entirely accidental/coincidental, as a developer can define these items at their whim (there are no standard naming conventions).